# Is is possible to change dynamically the array expression of a PHP foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have few arrays that store pages configurations, they have the same indexes and other similar configurations. Their name is always followed by `Config`:

```
$welcomeConfig = array (
  "title" => "welcome to my website",
  "other_settings"
);
$contactsConfig = array (
  "title" => "contact us",
  "other_settings"
);
```

Since I don't want to hard code every page with a custom `foreach loop` I wondered if it were possible to define a variable, concatenate it with the `Config` string and then use it as an array expression.

I tried in this way:

```
$custom = "welcome";
$custom .= "Config";

foreach ($custom as $config) {
  echo $config;
}
```

but it does not work.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @splash58 thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

$custom = "welcome";
$custom .= "Config";

foreach ($$custom as $config)
{
    echo $config;
}
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Yes sorry but stackoverflow didn't allow me to mark as correct. I had to wait 5 minutes.